# Is it possible to save individual char values taken from iterating through a string?

Tags: java

Java Student here working on the Roman Calculator problem. I am trying to take a given string of Roman numerals pass it through a for loop and save each individual numeral as a char so that I can convert it into an Integer value in the following method. Is there a way to save the values of each of these chars to a variable or possibly an array and call upon it in my next method to assign it a value? Here is what I have thus far:

```
int getOperand(int which) {
    System.out.println("Enter operand " + which);
    boolean invalid_operand;

    do {
        invalid_operand = false;

        String operand = keyboard.nextLine();
        int length = operand.length();
        if (operand.length() == 0)
            invalid_operand = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            char c = operand.charAt(i);

            if (c != 'M' || c != 'D' || c != 'C' || c != 'L' || c != 'X'
                    || c != 'V' || c != 'I') {
                invalid_operand = true;
                System.out.println("Invalid Numberal!");
            }
            char numeral = operand.charAt(i);
        }
    } while (invalid_operand);
     return which;
}
```

Comment: Side note: `if (c != 'M' || c != 'D' ...)` will **always** be true: `c` can't be both `'M'` and `'D'` simultaneously, so one or the other of those conditions will be true, and `||` is true when its left operand OR its right operand (or both) is true. You probably wanted `&&` (AND), not `||`.

Comment: Nice catch T.J, I am still a bit unpracticed with those conditions would && work better?

Comment: For that `if`, you definitely want `&&`, yes.

Comment: Because of DeMorgan's law, you could alternatively change each `!=` to `==` and negate the entire condition, resulting in `if (!(c == 'M' || c == 'D' ...)) {...`

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing from the other answer posted and making some further modifications to your method, I believe you could do what you asked about (storing the chars entered for use by another method) in either of the ways I've posted below.  The first returns a list of Integers corresponding to the chars which are valid.  The second instead returns this list as Characters.

Please note however that I have doubts about whether either is the way you are supposed to tackle the problem. It seems you may have been given a template and are to fill in the gaps. Is this true? If I am correct that the return type of the method (int) is part of a template you have been given, you shouldn't change it. It seems to me that this method is supposed to take an operand (for example CLII, the Roman Numeral representing 152) and return an int (in this case 152). If I am wrong about this, then I would need further clarification in order to know what this method is actually supposed to do.

The name 'getOperand' seems to indicate nothing more than reading the user input and storing it for future use, but then why would the return type be int? If the expected input is a series of chars, a return type of int would suggest to me that the method converts the Roman Numerals entered into an integer (integer rather than Integer. I'm using the word integer here to refer to what is going on: conversion of Roman Numerals to integers (such as the integer 152) as opposed to Integer (a Java class which which you might choose to use to help to achieve this)).

Perhaps you can clarify what the method is supposed to do, whether or not part of the method was given to you from the outset and if so, exactly which part/s was/were given to you and what you added yourself.

Now that I've said that, here are the two methods I mentioned above.

Method 1 (as Integers):

```
 /* changed the return type of the method to ArrayList<Integer> so that when 
    you call the method from another, you retrieve an ArrayList containing 
    just the Integers corresponding to the chars you want */

ArrayList<Integer> getOperand(int which) {
    System.out.println("Enter operand " + which);
    boolean invalid_operand;
    ArrayList<Integer> numerals = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    do {
        invalid_operand = false;

        String operand = keyboard.nextLine();
        int length = operand.length();
        if (operand.length() == 0)
            invalid_operand = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            char c = operand.charAt(i);

            if (c != 'M' && c != 'D' && c != 'C' && c != 'L' && c != 'X'
                    && c != 'V' && c != 'I') {
                invalid_operand = true;
                System.out.println("Invalid Numberal!");
            }
            else
            // else the char is valid, so add it to the ArrayList to be returned
            {
            char numeral = operand.charAt(i);
            numerals.add(numeral);
            }

        }
    } while (invalid_operand);
     return numerals;
}
```

Method 2 (as Characters):

```
/* changed the return type of the method to ArrayList<Character> so that when 
   you call the method from another, you retrieve an ArrayList containing 
   just the Characters corresponding to the chars you want */

ArrayList<Character> getOperand(int which) {
    System.out.println("Enter operand " + which);
    boolean invalid_operand;
    ArrayList<Character> numerals = new ArrayList<Character>();

    do {
        invalid_operand = false;

        String operand = keyboard.nextLine();
        int length = operand.length();
        if (operand.length() == 0)
            invalid_operand = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            char c = operand.charAt(i);

            if (c != 'M' && c != 'D' && c != 'C' && c != 'L' && c != 'X'
                    && c != 'V' && c != 'I') {
                invalid_operand = true;
                System.out.println("Invalid Numberal!");
            }
            else
            // else the char is valid, so add it to the ArrayList to be returned
            {
            char numeral = operand.charAt(i);
            Character character = new Character(numeral);
            numerals.add(character);
            }

        }
    } while (invalid_operand);
     return numerals;
}
```

In fact a cleaner way of doing it might be simply to change the return type to String, instantiate a new String instead of an ArrayList (setting its initital value to '') and append each valid char to it. (Having said that I would reiterate that you shouldn't make this or any other change to the return type if it was given to you as a template to build upon). This should be straight forward enough, but it is a useful exercise for you to find out how to find the answers to such exercises for yourself. I would google 'String append' as a starting point and take a look at the links that come up to see if there is anything that can help. You might want to look at the StringBuilder class too, to see if that is the best class to use. You may find that the String class has everything you need, without having to use StringBuilder.

If you aren't familiar with the manipulation of the ArrayList, Integer and Character classes (or any other class for that matter), I'd suggest you google (for example) 'ArrayList Java' and take a look at the documentation in the first link, where you can find a list of the methods and other useful information. You may not understand everything immediately, but it's helpful for anyone learning to familiarise themselves with this (my former lecturer said so). I believe it's known as 'the Java doc'.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71494/discussion-on-answer-by-george-tomlinson-is-it-possible-to-save-individual-char).

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> numerals = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    char c = operand.charAt(i);

    if (c != 'M' && c != 'D' && c != 'C' && c != 'L' && c != 'X'
            && c != 'V' && c != 'I') {
        invalid_operand = true;
        System.out.println("Invalid Numeral!");
    } else {
        // Use lists to save any numerals. You can access values
        // in the list just like in an array
        // Added the else in order to stop adding invalid numerals
        // to the list, as suggested by @Tom.
        numerals.add(c); 
    }   
}
// Do something with the list after it has all the valid numerals
```

Comment: I've edited your post to reflect that the `List` should be instantiated outside of the loop, and used `myList.add(c)` in stead of `numeral`. Just a heads up (now just wait for the accept or edit it yourself).

Comment: What is the point in checking if the numeral is valid if you add it to the valid numerals?

Comment: @Tom thanks for the suggestion, I added an else to make it more logical.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions guys. Looks great! I have yet to cover arrays/lists in my class yet so ill just do a bit of independent study and integrate these ideas into my program. Thanks a bunch!